# How to acquire an XML Element Value using C#

Tags: deserialization

The XML is being returned by a web API and it looks like this (but with more elements).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root response="True">
<movie title="TRON" />
</root>
```

I have C# that can query the Web API and then display the XML in the console. I need to be able to just display a specific element's value. For this example, I want to display the "title" element's value.

I have this C# code that just returns a blank console window.

```
    // Process the XML HTTP response
    static public void ProcessResponse(XmlDocument MovieResponse)
    {
        //This shows the contents of the returned XML (MovieResponse) in the console window//
        //Console.WriteLine(MovieResponse.InnerXml);
        //Console.WriteLine();

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(MovieResponse.NameTable);
        XmlNode mTitle = MovieResponse.SelectSingleNode("/root/movie/title", nsmgr);

        Console.WriteLine(mTitle);

        Console.ReadLine();
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something along these lines:

```
public List<string> GetMovieTitle(XDocument xdoc)
{
string xpath = @"//root/movie/title";
var query = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(xpath).Select(t => t.Value);

return query.ToList<string>();
}
```

More options can be found here : http://www.intertech.com/Blog/query-an-xml-document-using-linq-to-xml/

Edit using XmlDocument :

```
static public  void ProcessResponse(XmlDocument MovieResponse)
{
    string xpath = @"//root/movie/@title";
    var query = MovieResponse.SelectSingleNode(xpath).Value;
    Console.WriteLine(query)  ;
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to just modify the ProcessResponse class that I already have.

Comment: This did the trick for this situation!! Thank you so very much! Now I can build more into this now that I see how to grab the element values. Thank You!